# Probability question using Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, inequality

Consider a random sample taken from a distribution. Use Chebyshev’s inequality to determine a
sample size that will be sufficient, whatever the distribution, for the probability to be at least 0.99
that the sample mean will be within two standard deviations of the mean of the distribution.

Obviously I have to use Chebyshev's inequality, but I really don't know how to apply it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: What do you understand about Chebyshev's Inequality?

Comment: I know it's distribution independent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a random variable $M$ whose mean, $\mu$, and variance, $\gamma^2$, exist, the Chebishev inequality states that $$P(|M-\mu|\ge u)\le\frac{\gamma^2}{u^2}.$$
That is, the Chebyshev inequality provide an upper bound for the probability that the random variable falls further away, from its mean, than $u$.

Assume that we have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables, $X_1$,$X_2$,...,$X_N$, with an existing common mean, $m$, and an existing common variance $\sigma^2$. Then, let's denote the average of our random variables by $M$.  That is, let  $$M=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i.$$
Obviously, the mean of the average:  $\mu=m$, and the variance of the average:  $\gamma^2=\frac{1}{N}\sigma^2$. So, we can apply the Chebishev inequality to estimate that the average, $M$, falls further away, from the mean, $m$, than an arbitrary $u$:
$$P(|M-m|\ge u)\le\frac{\sigma^2}{Nu^2}.$$ 
In our case $u=2\sigma$. That is,
$$P(|M-m|\ge 2\sigma)\le\frac{1}{4N}.$$
The requirement of the OP is that this probability be less that $0.01$. This requirement will be met if  $$N>25.$$
Or, if the OP's request is that $u=\sigma$ then
$$P(|M-m|\ge \sigma)\le\frac{1}{N}.$$ So $N>100$ is the solution.